# Angular 7: Display value when click on Radio button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some problem with radio button. I need to display value when click on the radio button. Let say, when click on weekly it display "weekly" at "Selection" element. I've tried to make it but it not work. Could you teach me where should I change or add to make it display.

This is my code.

HTML

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

  <label *ngFor="let order of orders">
    <input formControlName="orders" type="radio" name="orders" [value]="order.id" />
    {{order.name}}
  </label>

  <br>
  <label *ngFor="let radiobutton of options">
    <input type="radio" class="justify-right" formControlName="options" name="options" [value]="radiobutton.id">{{radiobutton.name}}
    </label>

   <p>Selection: {{options.name}}</p>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my component code

TS

```
    form: FormGroup;
  orders = [];
  options = []

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: [''],
      options: ['']
    });

    // mimic async orders
    of(this.getOrders()).subscribe(orders => {
      this.orders = orders;
      this.form.controls.orders.patchValue(this.orders[0].id);
    });

    // getOptions
    of(this.getOptions()).subscribe(options => {
      this.options = options;
      this.form.controls.options.patchValue(this.options[0].id);
    })

    // synchronous orders
    // this.orders = this.getOrders();
    // this.form.controls.orders.patchValue(this.orders[0].id);
  }

  getOrders() {
    return [
      { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
      { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
      { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
      { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
    ];
  }

  getOptions(){
        return[
          {id: 'Once', name: 'Once'},
          {id: 'Daily', name: 'Daily'},
          {id: 'Weekly', name: 'Weekly'},
          {id: 'Interval', name: 'Interval'},
        ]
      }

      ngOnInit(){
        this.options
      }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

For reference you can refer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-radio-list)

Hope you all can help..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace one line.

with

```
<p>Selection: {{options.name}}</p>
```

below one.

```
<p>Selection: {{form.controls['options'].value}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use this value outside of just displaying it, you will want to use ngModel. To do so in your case:

Change your input to

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selection" type="radio" class="justify-right" formControlName="options" name="options" [value]="radiobutton.id">
```

And then add this to your typescript file under options

```
selection: String;
```

And change your selection print to

```
Selection: {{selection}}
```

Now if you want to use this value at any point in your TypeScript functions, simply call it using **this.selection**

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a formcontrol assosiated with formGroup you can't access options form control like options.name instead you can use getters

> A getter provides easy access to the aliases in the form control
>   instance compared to repeating the form.get('options') method to get
>   each instance.

```
get Options(){
        return this.form.get('options').value;
 }
```

Ref:https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-accessing-the-formarray-control

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-radio-list-pyad5s

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `form` variable to access the `options` directly in the HTML or you can use a getter in your component and display that in your HTML.

To display selected value directly using `form`

```
<p>Selection: {{form.get('options').value}}</p>
```

To display selected value using a getter

**component**

```
get optionsValue() {
  return this.form.get('options').value;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Selection: {{optionsValue}}</p>
```